# How to download data from a web page

Tags: data

I wonder if there is a way that I can get the data from a website automatically.
Here's a sample link:
http://www.trademap.org/CompaniesList.aspx?nvpm=1|704||||03|||4|1|1|2|3|1|1|1|1

You can download the dataset by clicking on the Excel icon. I tried to look for the exact link of the Excel file but didnt succeed. Is there away to find out the link that was used to download when clicking on the Excel icon?
If this isn't possible is there a way to get the data from the data automatically. I know how to change all the parameters; just don't know how to retrieve the data.
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Programmers.SE! You might want to check out: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: How is this not applicable here. The OP is looking for the architecture of analysing a HTTP request, but doesn't yet know how to ask for it?

Comment: sorry what happened? I didn't down vote your answer. In fact i already approved it as an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To find out what is happening with a http request, simply open the Inspector on Google Chrome and go to the Network tab, before you initiate the request.

In the resulting request and response, you can see the request under Headers when you click on the entry (Bilateral_TS.aspx).

You see how this is a POST request and it submits lots of Form Data at the bottom. You have to analyse which of this form data you send to get the data you want.

There is also a __VIEWSTATE variable which may be required or it may not be. If it is required simply request the original form first: view-source:http://www.trademap.org/Bilateral_TS.aspx?nvpm=1|704||004||03|||4|1|1|2|2|1|1|1|1 and you'll get this variable from the content.

To connect to a HTTP host, most people use the curl library or a more abstracted library. The best method to extract data from the website source code are regular expressions.

Comment: Why would my answer have been downvoted?